# Corrplot insig is blank for both colours and text

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to make a `corrplot` in R using the following code:

```
cord <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot(PD_Cor$r, method="color", col=col(200),  
         type="upper", order="hclust", 
         addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
         tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
         insig = "blank",# Combine with significance
         p.mat = PD_Cor$P, sig.level = 0.05,
         # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
         diag=FALSE 
)
```

The code produces a correlation triangle, where the insignificant values are completely blank.

I would like to have the r values displayed, just the square colour to be blank. Please find an example in the image below:

[image]

Comment: could you provide `PD_Cor` or dummy data in your question?